# Bitwise negation on double throws error

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, precision

Its late night and Im little embarrased to ask:

Why bitwise negation on `double` type throws error?

I understand how [double-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is stored in memory, but I sure am missing something...

```
double left = 1;
double nLeft = ~(left);

error: invalid argument type 'double' to unary expression
  double nLeft = ~(left);
                 ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: What do you think "bitwise negation" of a **double** would do? Turn -1 into 0? No, it won't.

Comment: The somewhat pedantic answer is that bitwise operations apply to integral types, and `double` is not an integral type.